# Rails move expensive method to task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduled-tasks, cron-task

I have these two methods in my model.  One method looks up a single CatalogItem facebook like count, and another that loops through  all active CatalogItems and finds their like counts using the aforementioned.

It takes a while to run through all active facebook likes...it might loop anywhere from 300-1000 objects; so i'd like to move this to some sort of cron, or whatever you guys suggest.

I was thinking I should add a column to CatalogItem called cached_fb_count, and adapt  **self.facebook_likes** to write to that colimn  whenever that task runs.

Is this the right approach?  What would that task look like if it was running every 2 hours?

```
def self.facebook_likes
  self.active.each_with_index do |i, index|
    _likes = i.facebook_like_count
    i.update_attribute(:cached_likes, _likes)
    # puts "#{index+1}   Likes:  #{_likes}  ###########   ID:  #{i.id}  "
  end
end

def facebook_like_count
  item_like_count = JSON.parse(open("https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url='https://www.foobar.com/catalog_items/#{self.id}'&format=json").read).first.flatten[1]
  item_like_count = item_like_count + 1 if item_like_count > 0 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) is a perfect tool for doing asynchronous tasks. It runs in a separate process, relation database-based (Active Record) so it saves context of execution as a simple script invokation. And has a rich functionality inculding task's priority and scheldue. but If you tasks assumes huge queues, consider [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler) gem. it uses Reddis as a storage for tasks and deals much faster with long queues.

Answer (score 0):

Use whenever its very easy to set up. Here is the link : `https://github.com/javan/whenever`